# Plain URLs from dynamic PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, apache, url-rewriting, dynamic-url

I am creating a question and answer site using PHP. Questions are viewed on one page using *'question.php?qid=1234'*, is the the correct thing to do, if so how to I make pages have URLs that search engines like StackOverflow *(e.g. 'http://mysite.com/question/1234')*. I am using  Apache and MySQL. I have add a look around but I still don't quite understand what to do. Thanks in advance :)

(Sorry if this has already been asked)

Comment: you can use .htaccess. Otherwise, learn PHP frameworks for this.

Comment: By the way, why was this voted down?

Comment: Some folks thinks this is not a worthy question. Regarding of the difficulty it is to you, it may be just plain easy on them, considering it as a not-to-asked question. Don't feel down with just a downvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you .htaccess file, wtite this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^question/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ question.php?qid=$1
```